# What's the english word for function's "zero extension"?

Tags: functions

What's the english word for function's "zero extension"?

Let $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the "zero extension" (or whatever it's called) to set $A \subset B$ is:

$$f^0:B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$f^0(x)=
\begin{cases}
f(x),  & x \in A \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: "Extension by zero", haven't seen any other terminology used.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)$ when $x \in A$?